# Track changes when updating a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do I check if the data is changed when I edit a record?

So before update

```
game.player=1
```

after update / edit

```
game.player=2
```

for example

how to track changes (check if changed) and do something in ruby on rails, when the data is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

You can check if a model has been changed by doing:

```
game.changed?
```

Or an individual field like:

```
game.player_changed?
```

Both return a boolean value.

Comment: thanks =) did it =)  so i just have to do something like if (game.changed? == true) then ... ?

Comment: or "game.changed? && XXX" or just "XXX if game.changed?"

Answer (score 3):

All changes are also kept in a hash. This comes in handy if you want to use the values.

```
game.changes #=> {:player => [1,2]}
```